# Removing model name doesn't display data. Why?

Tags: sapui5

I was able to display my output list if I include OData model name in the path of  the "items". But when I removed the OData model, it did not work. Why?

```xml
<List items="{myOdata>/SalesOrderSet}">
  <StandardListItem
    title="{myOdata>SalesOrderID}"
    type="Navigation"
    press=".goToDets"
  />
</List>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should always use this rule when your model is not the default one (default is when the model has no name).

```
<List items="{ModelName>/ListOfValues}" id="list0">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem type="Navigation" title="{ModelName>Title}" description="{ModelName>Description}" icon="sap-icon://picture" id="item0" press="GoToDets"/>
    </items>
</List>
```

If you're using the default model you should use this kind of template:

```
<List items="{/ListOfValues}" id="list0">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem type="Navigation" title="{Title}" description="{Description}" icon="sap-icon://picture" id="item0" press="GoToDets"/>
    </items>
</List>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kcx72Lbs/)

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. I noticed that if a model name is used the getBindingContext("<model name>") is required instead of getBindingContext().

Comment: Hi Richard, yes it's for the same reason. If you pass nothing, it's using the default model (empty). You have to specify the model name if you're using a specific model ;)